# Personalize the Email Content

Tags: outbound-email

I am trying to personalize the Email page contents. I have added a target group based on Tracking key in the Email page component presentation.

When I am previewing in CME the page it works fine with the corresponding Target group. But when I am sending the page using outbound Mail to different users, the contents don't get personalized.In this case all the contents of the page are rendered irrespective of the different user.

I have created the Target group using the Keyword and assign the value as 1, and I have attached the same keyword 2 out of the 5 contacts. But while sending the mail all the users are getting the same content.
In the Email Page template I have addeed the following TBBs

1. Outbound Email Pre-Processing
2. Outbound Email Post-Processing
3. Target Group Personalization
4. The Custom dreamweaver TBB

Am I missing anything?

Comment: As you have not mentioned here, have you also selected `include` for the keyword(s) you selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that the Post-Processing TBB is after your Dreamweaver template (hence its name) -- and remove the Target Group Personalization. That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Its working now after repositioning the TBBs